# NOT GETTING REDIRECT RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, express

In `app.post("/compose")`, I am trying to redirect the URL to the home page, but it's not redirecting to the homepage.
What mistake am I making?
Kindly help, redirecting to the homepage `res.redirect("/")` not working.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const homeStartingContent = "HOME CONTENT ........";
const aboutContent = "ABOUT CONTENT .......";
const contactContent = "CONTACT CONTENT ......";

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

var posts = [];

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home", {homeContent: homeStartingContent});
  console.log(posts);
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about", {aboutContent: aboutContent});
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
  res.render("contact", {contactContent: contactContent});
});

app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose");
});

app.post("/compose", function(req, res){

  const post = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  };
  posts.push(post);
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to redirect when I ran your code in local by changing this:-

res.render("home", {homeContent: homeStartingContent});

to

res.send("I am in get method");

This means your code is working fine. The problem could be with your "home" page.
Could be an issue rendering it.

With your code, I was getting the following error:-

Failed to lookup view "home"

This was because there was no file named "home".

Is your code working fine in your system? If there is an error, please enter that in your question.

Comment: Yes the code is working fine on my system and I am not getting any errors but I can't understand why it's not redirected to home page.

Comment: You are very welcome. You can tell us where was the problem. Answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a typing mistake from my side. Instead of passing  **action="/compose" method="post"** into the form element, i mistakenly passed into the div element(like that **div class="form-group" action="/compose" method="post"**).

```
<%- include('partials/header'); -%>

<h1>COMPOSE</h1>

<form class="form-group" action="/compose" method="post">
  <div>
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postTitle">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Post</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="25" name="postBody"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Publish</button>
</form>

<%- include('partials/footer'); -%>
```